Django CSRF error with request on multiple tabs simultaneously
I am working on a Django project and have encountered an issue with CSRF tokens when rendering a page with a form.
To reproduce the issue, I added a 5-second delay when rendering the page. Here is the scenario:

I open the URL with the form in the first browser tab.
Within 5 seconds, I open the same URL in a second tab, ensuring that the first request hasn't yet completed.

As a result, the first tab generates a csrftoken, and the second tab overrides it. However, the csrfmiddlewaretoken in the form on the first tab remains bound to the old csrftoken.
When I submit the form from the first tab, a CSRF error occurs due to the mismatch.
Could you please help to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

update: reproduce repo
